# InnoDB on Spring Boot 2.0.x?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, innodb

How to configure the "hibernate.dialect.storage_engine = innodb" property in Spring Boot 2.0.x, please ?

- Spring Boot 2.0.5.RELEASE
- MySQL Community Server 8.0.11

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

MySQL Server Variables:

```
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
default_tmp_storage_engine=InnoDB
```

Spring Boot Console output:

```
Hibernate: 

    drop table if exists person
Hibernate: 

    create table person (
       id bigint not null auto_increment,
        address varchar(255),
        age integer,
        city varchar(255),
        info varchar(255),
        telephone varchar(255),
        zip_code varchar(255),
        email varchar(255) not null,
        first_name varchar(255) not null,
        last_name varchar(255) not null,
        version bigint,
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=MyISAM
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect`

Comment: The class `MySQL5InnoDBDialect` is Deprecated. Set using JVM parameter `-Dhibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```