# Transactional doesn't roll back on checked exception in Spring Boot with Data JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions, unirest

I have a `ProcessRecon` usecase class with a single method named `execute`. It saves an entity `Reconciliation` using `paymentRepository.saveRecon` and calls a web service as part of acknowledgement using `paymentRepository.sendReconAck`.

Now there's a chance that this external web service might fail in which case I want to rollback the changes i.e. the saved entity. Since I am using Unirest, it throws UnirestException which is a checked exception.

There are no errors on the console but this will probably be helpful **[UPDATED]**.

```
2020-08-20 17:21:42,035 DEBUG [http-nio-7012-exec-6] org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager: Creating new transaction with name [com.eyantra.payment.features.payment.domain.usecases.ProcessRecon.execute]:PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,-com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException
...
2020-08-20 17:21:44,041 DEBUG [http-nio-7012-exec-2] org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager: Initiating transaction rollback
2020-08-20 17:21:44,044 DEBUG [http-nio-7012-exec-2] org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(621663440<open>)]
2020-08-20 17:21:44,059 DEBUG [http-nio-7012-exec-2] org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
2020-08-20 17:22:40,020 DEBUG [http-nio-7012-exec-2] org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor: Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
```

What I see at the moment is that entity gets pushed to database even if there's a `UnirestException`. But I expect no data be saved to database.

I am using Spring Boot 2.3.3 with MySQL 5.7. This is the code I have for it.

**ProcessRecon.java**

```
@Usecase // this custom annotation is derived from @service
public class ProcessRecon {

    private final PaymentRepository paymentRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ProcessRecon(PaymentRepository paymentRepository) {
        this.paymentRepository = paymentRepository;
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = UnirestException.class)
    public Reconciliation execute(final Reconciliation reconciliation) throws UnirestException {
        
        PaymentDetails paymentDetails = paymentRepository.getByReqId(reconciliation.getReqId());

        if (paymentDetails == null)
            throw new EntityNotFoundException(ExceptionMessages.PAYMENT_DETAILS_NOT_FOUND);
        reconciliation.setPaymentDetails(paymentDetails);

        Long transId = null;
        if (paymentDetails.getImmediateResponse() != null)
            transId = paymentDetails.getImmediateResponse().getTransId();

        if (transId != null)
            reconciliation.setTransId(transId);

        if (reconciliation.getTransId() == null)
            throw new ValidationException("transId should be provided in Reconciliation if there is no immediate" +
                    " response for a particular reqId!");

        // THIS GETS SAVED
        Reconciliation savedRecon = paymentRepository.saveRecon(reconciliation);
        paymentDetails.setReconciliation(savedRecon);
        
        // IF THROWS SOME ERROR, ROLLBACK
        paymentRepository.sendReconAck(reconciliation);
        return savedRecon;
    }
}
```

**PaymentRepositoryImpl.java**

```
@CleanRepository
public class PaymentRepositoryImpl implements PaymentRepository {

    @Override
    public String sendReconAck(final Reconciliation recon) throws UnirestException {
        // Acknowledge OP
        return sendAck(recon.getRequestType(), recon.getTransId());
    }

    String sendAck(final String requestType, final Long transId) throws UnirestException {
        // TODO: Check if restTemplate can work with characters (requestType)
        final Map<String, Object> queryParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        queryParams.put("transId", transId);
        queryParams.put("requestType", requestType);

        logger.debug("{}", queryParams);

        final HttpResponse<String> result = Unirest.get(makeAckUrl()).queryString(queryParams).asString();

        logger.debug("Output of ack with queryParams {} is {}", queryParams, result.getBody());
        return result.getBody();
    }

    @Override
    public Reconciliation saveRecon(final Reconciliation recon) {
        try {
            return reconDS.save(recon);
        }
        catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
            throw new EntityExistsException(ExceptionMessages.CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION);
        }
    }
}
```

**ReconciliationDatasource.java**

```
@Datasource // extends from @Repository
public interface ReconciliationDatasource extends JpaRepository<Reconciliation, Long> {
    List<Reconciliation> findByPaymentDetails_User_Id(Long userId);
}
```

Comment: Could you please try by adding `rollbackFor = Exception.class`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had tried that before and again on your suggestion. It doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed the default engine for the tables would be **InnoDB** but to my surpise, the tables were created using **MyISAM** engine which doesn't support transactions.

I resolved the problem by using the below property as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52580809/innodb-on-spring-boot-2-0-x)

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

**instead of**

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

That was the only change required. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To make annotations work you have to use interfaces instead of classes for dependency injection.

```
interface ProcessRecon {
      Reconciliation execute(final Reconciliation reconciliation) 
          throws UnirestException;
}
```

Then

```
@Usecase
public class ProcessReconImpl implements ProcessRecon {

    private final PaymentRepository paymentRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ProcessReconImpl(PaymentRepository paymentRepository) {
        this.paymentRepository = paymentRepository;
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = UnirestException.class)
    public Reconciliation execute(final Reconciliation reconciliation) throws UnirestException {
        //method implementation...
    }
}
```

Usage

```
@Autowired
ProcessRecon processRecon;

public void executeServiceMethod(Reconciliation reconciliation) {
    processRecon.execute(reconciliation)
}
```

This way you have got proxy of `ProcessReconImpl` with provided by annotations additional functionality.

Comment: Where do I put the transactional annotation with the above fix? I put it first on exeute and then on controller but record is still commited to DB. If it helps these lines are also there in the log.
"org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager: Initiating transaction rollback
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager 
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager: Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction"

Comment: `ProcessReconImpl::execute` have to be annotated as `@Transactional`. I have edited the answer

Comment: As far as I understand `sendReconAck` has nothing to do with your database. Why `PaymentRepositoryImpl` contains this method? Repository have to contain database related methods only.

Comment: All queries inside of a transaction must be on the same connection. It is a wrong desicion to use external connection (http request) inside transaction.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer my question. Is it that transactions should only be used for anything data related. If a query in future fails only then undo the previous database change? So how do I handle undoing the changes to the database caused by anything else in the service method that fails?

Comment: Your transaction is supposed to work. But it can cause database connection problems due to external connection request.

Comment: I had about the same problem in tests. I was using MySL with Spring Data JPA Test but individual test methods wouldn't rollback. The problem solved when I switched to H2. Could that issue be related? I am using HikariCP with MySQL.

Comment: Try to add `throw new UnirestException()` after row `paymentRepository.saveRecon(reconciliation)` and test

Comment: The result doesn't change. I can see the row still persisting. This is what tomcat would show in the exception caused by: com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException: Roll back now.